# jQuery isn't loading and '$' is undefined in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to do a very basic thing with jQuery, and it's not working at all in IE8 but works fine in Firefox, Safari and Chrome; IE gives me an "Object Expected" all the time.

Can anyone help?  I'm not sure what is wrong as the page is very basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { 
            alert("It works!");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

IE (and only IE) gives me an error saying "Object Expected" on the loading code.  I have the IE Dev Toolbar and `$` is undefined but in Firebug it comes up as "function".  really don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Is IE 404ing on `jquery-1.5.2.min.js`?

Comment: Works for me. I tested it from my local filesystem (rather than through a webserver) and had to grant permissions to IE to run scripts on local pages. I was prompted to do this by an infobar. Perhaps this is tripping you up?

Comment: @MattBall: Browsers do not 404.

Comment: I had the infobar and said yes to allow scripts.  Also going to the URL itself IE prompts me to open/save it.

Comment: @Tomalak: you know what I mean, though. Fine, I'll spell it out: "Does Internet Explorer receive an HTTP response with status code 404 when requesting the resource located at `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js`?"

Comment: @MattBall: If IE8 did, Firefox would too.

Comment: Download Fiddler2 and watch the responses, and see what the server hosting the scripts is responding with. It's probably an error code.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) method of:

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

**EDIT**:

Btw ... I use this from IE6-IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera and I don't ever have an issue with $ being undefined.  If you have plugins, I would use this pattern to ensure variables are what they should be:

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    // code here

})(jQuery, this, document);
```

Comment: I tried downloading it locally as well in case it was something with the CDN; same thing happens.  Firefox picks it up fine, IE doesn't.

Comment: The problem has to be within your browser setting somewhere then.  I just did this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TenE/) and tested your copy/pasted code.  I opened it in IE8 and I got the alert.

Comment: In fact, just to make sure, I copy/pasted your code into notepad, saved as test.html and opened in IE8.  I got a message about running scripts or ActiveX controls. I clicked to allow blocked content and it ran.

Comment: @JackNicholson - No problem.  Glad it did!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel like an idiot.  I don't know how (I certainly didn't change it!) but somehow my IE was disabling JavaScript, so no wonder it was not working!  I only use FireFox when I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue before. It can be caused by a number of things, but the simplest solution I've found is using "jQuery" in place of a dollar sign.

```
jQuery(function() { 
            alert("It works!");
});
```

Comment: Same thing as before; "object expected" and typing 'jQuery' in the Fiddler console returns "'jQuery' is undefined"

Comment: Have you tried referencing a local copy of jquery instead of the one at http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js?

Answer (score 0):

you could try alternative syntax for initiating like this:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){

    })
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Alternative syntax is not going to change that `$` and `jQuery` are not defined.

Comment: @Tomalak no downvote here ? not that I want to encourage you with your 226 downvotes

Comment: @mcgrailm: Is that snippiness?

Answer (score -1):

This [works](http://kera.name/test.html) perfectly well in my copy of Internet Explorer 8.0.7600.16385 on Windows 7.

Something must be up with your browser configuration.

Comment: @Allan: It's a shame that you neglected to mention that in your question; it points even more to some mitigating circumstance.

Answer (score -5):

You probably need to put your function in the ready eventhandler like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function() {
     alert("It works!");
   }):
});
```

That way the entire dom has been processed before your function gets run.

Comment: $() is just shorthand for $(document).ready() in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: (a) No he doesn't, because he's not using the DOM. (b) He's already doing this. (c) You're still trying to use `$`, and the problem is that his `$` is not defined properly.

Comment: Your right, my bad.  I didn't realize that was the shorthand for $document.ready().  And I was assuming that jquery wasn't being loaded before the function definition.