# JQuery not supported in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Always having problems with `IE`.

In my web page I included locally `JQuery` as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsp/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsp/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsp/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsp/tajweed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsp/tajweed-tools.js"></script>
```

But, it gives these errors:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 10:17:38 UTC


Message: 'JSON' is undefined
Line: 4
Char: 562
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/play/jsp/jquery-2.0.2.min.js


Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 6
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/play/jsp/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 37
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/play/jsp/init.js


Message: Object expected
Line: 2
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/play/jsp/tajweed.js
```

I searched in some topics such [TOPIC 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553974/jquery-isnt-loading-and-is-undefined-in-ie8) and [TOPIC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323729/jquery-validate-1-8-1-jquery-is-undefined-error-ie8) but in vain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jquery 2.x explicitly doesn't support IE8.

Use the 1.x versions if you want to support this browser.

From [the download page](http://jquery.com/download/) :

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.